# Alignment issue in Area 51 discussion - search result page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, area-51

There is a minor alignment issue in the Area 51 Discussion Search result page.

The text search text box is overlapped with the text "Search".

[image: Search text box]

Sample search query: https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=angular

The issue is in Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox with 100% Zoom.

Comment: Also confirmed in Edge and IE11.